# javascript clear php post return in modal window

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a small form inside of a modal window.  The window pops up when a link is clicked.

The form has 2 buttons, submit and close.

After something is submitted, the form posts to php.  Php returns a thank you message.  When I click the close button, it clears the info from the form, but it doesn't clear the thank you message, that remains.

How can I accomplish this?  Here is my code.  Thank you in advance.

The form

```
 <div class="panel3">
 <form id="form1" onsubmit="return submitForm2();">
 <input type="text" name="url" size="34" />
 <textarea placeholder="Please tell us why this should be reviewed." style="resize:none" name="flag" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
 <input type="button" onclick="formReset()" value="Close" class="trigger3" />
 <div class="form_result2"></div>
 </form>
 </div>
```

and the script

```
 <script>
 function formReset(){
 document.getElementById("form1").reset();
 }
 </script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the "Thank you" message displaying? If it is inside the "form_result2", the reset() function won't clear the message. That function only clears the form elements. You have to clear the "form_result2" div separately.

You can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("form_result2").item(0).innerHTML="";
```